# Soundcloud likes from Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Assuming I've gotten access to the user_likes permission, I can't find the endpoint that gets me a user's Soundcloud likes from their Facebook open graph. I'm trying to use the `v2.4/me?fields=likes` node but it only returns pages I've liked. None of the likes that appear in my own activity feed are returned. Is there a different endpoint I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused. The "likes" an Soundcloud are not Facebook likes IMHO, at least there is no indication that they're an `og.like` action. Soundcloud would also need the according permission to be able like objects via facebook Graph API.

At least for my user account I can say that Soundcloud doesn't have those permissions.

If they WOULD be OpenGraph likes, you could query them via

```
/me/og.likes
```

But be aware that there are no additional filtering possibilities, meaning you'd have to filter in your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes/#read

Comment: I say that because in my activity log, the tracks I've liked in SoundCloud appear under the "Likes" tab. Also, I could filter by app, but I have no idea how to find the app ID for Soundcloud.

Comment: If I push the "heart" button in my Soundcloud iOS app, and also in the browser version, no like is posted to Facebook. Also, I'm not asked for any permissions. What steps did you take?

Comment: From your desktop, you need to connect your FB account with Soundcloud from your Soundcloud social settings. Make sure you check the boxes that publish your likes to FB, and it should work for you

Comment: I did do that long ago. Probably I'd have to disconnect the app first via FB settings. If I look at the source code of a single track on Soundcloud, I see this: `<meta content="19507961798" property="fb:app_id">` When I query `/19507961798` one can see that the namespace is `soundcloud`. This should correspond to the value of the OG object's `type` when querying `/me/og.likes`

Comment: Aha! `/me/og.likes` was the answer I was looking for. I was querying `/me/likes`. Thank you